# Syntax highlighting for ruby function calls in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've been trying to get proper synax coloring going for Ruby using Sublime 3 for a while now, and have finally tired of hitting my head against the wall.

I want to be able to give the various function calls different color than the remaining ruby code, but I cannot find a way to target them in my **.tmTheme** file (I've tried meta.function-call, meta.function-call-ruby etc. to no avail).

So, how can I target the "before_action" method call in my .tmTheme file (Do I have to edit the .tmLanguage file for ruby, and if so, God help me).

[image: Screenshot]

According to Scope Hunter, the scope for this is simply just *source.ruby* (see screenshot).

[image]

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution by adding support for rails in Sublime, which changes the scope of certain methods to `source.rails.controller.actions`